# Loaded class count in Tomcat keep going up

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat

I'm using Java Melody to monitor one of our apps that is a standard J2EE app, deployed in Tomcat 6, with Apache 2 as the front end, using AJP.  There are two instances that sit behind an F5.  Things seem fairly normal, and it's a low volume app; it averages about 200 hits a minute, uses about 4% of the CPU, and averages 350 meg of memory.  The one thing that is troubling me is the loaded class count; after three days, one JVM is at 752k, and the other at 741k.  Three is a direct corilation of usage with class-count increase

In looking around stackoverflow, there seem to be a lot of posts of this happening when the app is stopped & restarted, or redeployed, in Tomcat.  That is not the case here.  Any time we redeploy, the entire thing is stopped, including Apache.

Any ideas how to figure out what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

You have not reported any OutOfMemory exceptions so may be these increasing classes are not a problem.

If the loaded class count is increasing, that means these are not getting garbage collected because *some references to these instances* still exist. May be these are some internal APIs or 3rd party libraries loaded by the application and sitting in memory.

There are 2 things I'd suggest:

A) Are your GC settings, [Xmx,Xms,NewSize](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) and the lot set to adequate values? You could post them to add to your question.

B) Profile the app and examine what's in the heap. Use VisualVM or Yourkit to obtain and analyze the heap dump.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue when running tomcat 7 on AIX.  After adding the java_opt "-Xincgc" it seemed to level out.